# Android - Can a general class (not extending Activity/Service) read file from the phone?

Tags: android, storage

Assume a class not extending Activity/Service, is it possible for it to read files or databases from the phone without using context?

I need the information in this class private, but if someone decompiles it, s/he can know everything "secret". So I think about putting this information into a file, and the class can retrieve it when it is needed.

Is it possible?

Answer: it won't be safer.

Comment: What is the connection between reading files and trying to make your class safe from decompilers?

Comment: I need the information in this class private, but if someone decompiles it, s/he can know everything "secret". So I think about putting this information into a file, and the class can retrieve it when it is needed.

Comment: Having information in the file won't help you secure it in any way.

Comment: yes, i finally notice it. thanks anyway.

Comment: Are these credentials for a network service, media, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to the filesystem is controlled by permissions, not which class contains the code.  And, anyone can read normal files off the storage by enabling developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do for file . Create an instance of File class to read file without  context.
 But accessing database in android require context by SQLiteOpenHelper class. Pass the context from your other activity class when you create an instance of your database helper class

Comment: So you mean I can write/read file by using FILE I/O without context? Is there any permission required?

Comment: I have another question: how to make the file can only be read by a certain class?

Comment: you cannot secure the file as its in a file system even if its in application folder. Instead encrypt and store the data in a database. Ensure you create a random encryption key on runtime or get it from backend.